# Can you use constraints on derived classes in CRTP methods?

Tags: c++, c++20, crtp

Is something like this valid C++20 code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
concept impls_decrement = requires(T it) { it.decrement(); };

template <class Derived>
struct iterator_facade {
  Derived& operator--()
    requires impls_decrement<Derived>
  {
    auto& self = static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    self.decrement();
    return self;
  }
};

struct my_iterator : iterator_facade<my_iterator> {
  void decrement() {
    std::cout << "decrement" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
   my_iterator iter;
   --iter;
   return 0;
}
```

Adapted from [vector-of-bool](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2020/06/13/cpp20-iter-facade.html) blog post.

With the latest version of gcc, the code works [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jLgywBFbjLvyOOcs), but the latest version of clang gives this [error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9bhcTamrjf8nEPre):

```
prog.cc:25:4: error: cannot decrement value of type 'my_iterator'
   --iter;
   ^ ~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: gcc is correct. This is basically [clang bug 44833](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44833). This is how `view_interface` is specified for Ranges.

Comment: `Derived` is incomplete within CRTP definition, but not for CRTP function members instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barry mentioned, the code is valid and this is Clang [bug 44833](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44833).

In the meantime, I was able to work around the issue by writing the code like this ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wsuR5Y5fNZFecWKY)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
concept impls_decrement = requires(T it) { it.decrement(); };

template <class Derived>
struct iterator_facade {
  template <class T=Derived>
    requires impls_decrement<T>
  Derived& operator--()
  {
    auto& self = static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    self.decrement();
    return self;
  }
};

struct my_iterator : iterator_facade<my_iterator> {
  void decrement() {
    std::cout << "decrement" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
   my_iterator iter;
   --iter;
   return 0;
}
```