# How can I constrain a Base Class with the Child class in a CRTP pattern?

Tags: c++, c++20

Here's a link to code:
https://godbolt.org/z/a3Eh6xhYP

Here's the actual code:

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename Model>
concept ShapeConcept = requires(Model shape){
    {shape.length()} -> std::same_as<double>;
    {shape.size()} -> std::same_as<double>;
};

// CRTP Base Class
template<ShapeConcept Shape>
class AreaCalculator{

    double getArea(){
        Shape& shape = static_cast<Shape&>(*this);
        return shape.length() * shape.size();
    }
};

// Class that I want to augment
class Box: AreaCalculator<Box> {
    double length(){
        return 1.0;
    }

    double size(){
        return 1.0;
    }
};
```

Here's the error with clang13:

```
<source>:20:12: error: constraints not satisfied for class template 'AreaCalculator' [with Shape = Box]
class Box: AreaCalculator<Box> {
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:10: note: because 'Box' does not satisfy 'ShapeConcept'
template<ShapeConcept Shape>
         ^
<source>:5:11: note: because 'shape.length()' would be invalid: member access into incomplete type 'Box'
    {shape.length()} -> std::same_as<double>;
          ^
```

I understand the error:
`Box` is not yet fully declared when `AreaCalculator<Box>` is invoked and so the parser cannot know that `Box` will satisfy the `ShapeConcept` constraint.

Is there a different way of constraining my CRTP base class or is this a limitation of C++20?

Edit:
After using some better search terms:
This should be marked as duplicated of this:
[Can you use constraints on derived classes in CRTP methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217479/can-you-use-constraints-on-derived-classes-in-crtp-methods)

The solution is not ideal, but it is acceptable:
https://godbolt.org/z/qeEjoevM8

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename Model>
concept ShapeConcept = requires(Model shape){
    {shape.length()} -> std::same_as<double>;
    {shape.size()} -> std::same_as<double>;
};

// CRTP Base Class
template<typename Shape>
struct AreaCalculator{

    template <typename T=Shape>
    double getArea()
    requires ShapeConcept<T>{
        Shape& shape = static_cast<Shape&>(*this);
        return shape.length() * shape.size();
    }
};

// Class that I want to augment
struct Box: AreaCalculator<Box>{
    double length(){
        return 2.0;
    }

    double size(){
        return 3.0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    return (int) Box().getArea(); 

}
```

This works as we are delaying the evaluation of the concept until the method is invoked, though it does introduce some potential for misuse.

Comment: Constraints cannot be used in this way. To define `Box`, we need to be able to know what `AreaCalculator<Box>` is. If instantiating `AreaCalculator<Box>` requires a complete definition of `Box`, we run into a circular dependency problem. One way to prevent instantiations like `AreaCalculator<int>` are to use [strategically placed static_asserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401401/constrained-crtp-premature-rejection)

Comment: I was in the middle of posting an answer that fits my needs based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217479/can-you-use-constraints-on-derived-classes-in-crtp-methods
The code is here: https://godbolt.org/z/qeEjoevM8
This works as we are delaying the evaluation of the concept until the method is declared, though it does introduce a place for misuse.